# How to pass query params to request made by DS.RestAdapter#findHasMany?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got Video model and I'm returning `links` param that points to `related` URL in JSON response from the API:

```
video: {
  id: 1,
  name: "Whatever",
  links: {
    related: "/videos/1/related"
  }
}
```

and have `related: hasMany('video', {async: true, inverse: null})` association in `Video` model. Calling `video.get('related')` makes request to `/videos/:id/related`. This part works fine.

How can I pass query params to ajax request to e.g. add pagination params? I'd like to make request like `/videos/:id/related?per=3&page=5`.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this and saw that this had remained unanswered - Not sure if the original poster had found a resolution. The way to do it would be to override the ajax call of RESTAdapter - I am sure there would be better ways to handle pagination but here's what needs to be done to send additional params.

```
App.VideoAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: HOST,
    // Overriding ajax request to include account_id as a parameter
    ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
        if (Ember.isEmpty(hash)) hash = {};
        if (Ember.isEmpty(hash.data)) hash.data = {};
        hash.data.per = App.per; // Global variable - Not the smartest thing to do and should do something else
        hash.data.page = App.page; // Global variable - Not the smartest thing to do and should do something else
        return this._super(url, type, hash);
    }
});
```